# Append string to variable with delimiter

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I need help solving this issue, i have a file which contains list of names:

#### names.txt

```
roger
peter
henry
```

I would like to concatenate `:` after every name

```
for i in $(cat names.txt); do
   $i+=$i":"
done
```

The output I want is this `roger:peter:henry`

but I am getting this output `roger:peter:henry:`

Comment: Well, yes:: that's what you are telling it to do. Two ways to fix it: treat the last name specially or delete the trailing `:` after the loop is done. In this case, the second one is easier.

Comment: You should read and understand about how `for i in ...` loop works. Your command does not output what you say ...

Comment: With that script and that input file, the output you get is `bash: roger+=roger:: command not found` etc. Please don't post code that is different from the one you use.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that can do it for you: `paste`

```
$ paste -sd: names.txt
roger:peter:henry
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `sed` and `tr`:

```
sed '$!s/$/:/' names.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

Ouputs:

```
roger:peter:henry
```

Answer (score 0):

`paste` is the right tool for the job. But just for the sake of completeness, here's how to do what you were attempting:

```bsh
k="$(head -n1 names.txt)";
for i in $(tail -n+2 names.txt); do 
    k="$k:$i"; 
done
```

This produces:

```
$ echo "$k"
roger:peter:henry
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i+=$i":"
```

This doesn't do what you want it to do. Instead, it expands `$i` in the marked places, and tries to run the result as a command. A shell assignment doesn't take the dollar sign on the left hand side (think of it as taking the value of the variable, here we don't want that, but the location to store in). It should be `i+=$i":"` instead. Or preferably `i+="$i:"` just to get in the habit of quoting shell variable expansions.

In addition, you're trying to append to the variable used as the loop variable. That's not very useful, since it gets overwritten on the next round of the loop. Also, you're adding a colon after each item, including the last, so you'll have one at the end. But we can remove it afterward with the `${var%suffix}` expansion.

So:

```
s=
for i in $(cat names.txt); do
   s+="$i:"
done 
s=${s%:}
```

Though beware that the unquoted expansion of `$(cat)` will process any filename wildcard patterns (globs), so a line `*` in the file will be expanded to all files in the current directory, etc.